# Automatically running multiple TFS 2015 Build Agents on same server and run the same build ?

Tags: tfs, tfsbuild, tfs-2015

Is it possible to automatically Run multiple TFS 2015 (vNext) Build Agents on same server and run the same build successfully?

Currently, we have one build agent on the Build machine. CI builds configured to run automatically for each commits, So far its good.

Now, Build server seems to be a bottleneck because the new mode of "pull request" creates even more builds requests, and we have to wait for the results.

I created another build agent / build queue. Don't know how to make the agents run parallelyy  automatically for CI builds.   Any ideas / help is appreciated .

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you can (see [Q&A section](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/build/concepts/agents/agents#can-i-install-multiple-private-agents-on-the-same-machine) of the docs).

The trick is to download the agent once again in a different directory so the two agents are insulated from one another.

Comment: Good to know that there is way and Thanks a lot for the trick. i just created another agent referring to the same agent pool. now i can see two agents. let see how it works. Thanks again ..!